# SignalR .net core is getting 401 for negotiate request when inside windows intranet

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, angular, signalr

I'm trying to get signalR to work with a .net core 2.2 application. I need to connect to it from an angular front end. I have another app that is seemingly configured the same way that already has signalR working. When I connect to the other app from the angular it works but if I try to connect to the original app I get a 401 error. the code involving signalR looks identical as far as I can tell.

We use windows intranet authentication. I don't have access to any of the devs who set this up originally but it's all in our windows intranet site and we login via an alert popup that I put my intranet info into.

Here's relevant code in startup.cs configure services

```
            services.AddCors();

        services.AddSignalR();
```

Here's in sertup.cs configure

```
var origins = Configuration.GetValue<string>("apiAllowedOrigins").Split(',');
        app.UseCors(builder =>
            builder.WithOrigins(origins)
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
            );

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<IbjaHub>("/ibjahub");
        });
```

Here's ibjahub

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace CapitalJobs.SignalR
{
    public class IbjaHub : Hub
    {
    }
}
```

Here's the angular code connecting to the hub

```
 this._ibjaService
  .getSignalRHub()
  .pipe(
    tap(hd => {
      const hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(hd.hubURL)
        .build();
      hubConnection
        .start()
        .then(() => {
          console.log('SignalR Connection started');
        })
        .catch(err => {
          this._toaster.pop({
            type: 'error',
            title: 'Connection Lost',
            body: `Connection to server lost, and attempts to reconnect failed. Please refresh the page.`,
            timeout: 0,
            bodyOutputType: BodyOutputType.TrustedHtml
          });
          console.error(err);
        });

      hubConnection.on(
        'todo: replace this with what its going to say',
        data => {
          if (data.username !== this._config.appMenu.userName) {
            return;
          }
          //todo parse the data about e1
        }
      );

      hubConnection.onclose((error?: Error) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error(error.message);
          window.setTimeout(() => {
            hubConnection
              .start()
              .then(() => {})
              .catch(err => {
                this._toaster.pop({
                  type: 'error',
                  title: 'Connection Lost',
                  body: `Connection to server lost, and attempts to reconnect failed. Please refresh the page.`,
                  timeout: 0,
                  bodyOutputType: BodyOutputType.TrustedHtml
                });
                console.error(err);
              })
              .then(() => {
                this._toaster.pop({
                  type: 'warning',
                  title: 'Connection Lost',
                  body: `Connection to server was lost, but was successfully reconnected. Some messages may have been lost. Please refresh the page if issues continue.`,
                  timeout: 0,
                  showCloseButton: true,
                  bodyOutputType: BodyOutputType.TrustedHtml
                });
              });
          }, 2000);
        }
      });
    })
  )
  .subscribe();
```

}

I used the same code to connect to the working api vs the one that doesn't work. Here's a side by side screen shot of the results of the options request.

[options request from calls to both apis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmQLj.png)

I've gone through many solutions on stack overflow as well as microsoft forums.

I tried adding a kestrel server line to program.cs.

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
            {
  
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>{}) // this line
            .UseNLog()
            .Build();
}
```

I've added forwarding the tokens in start up both shown below.

```
            services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options => {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                        ValidIssuer = "<issuer removed>",
                        ValidAudience = "<audience removed>",
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                                                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["CapitalJobs:JWTSigningKey"]))
                    };
```